# How do you debug the Azure Java SDK CosmosClient SSL handshake?

Tags: ssl, azure-cosmosdb, netty, azure-sdk

How do you debug the Azure Java SDK CosmosClient connection SSL handshake?

I tried with Commons-Logging and with SLF4j, and cannot get the SSL handshake to put out debug output.   Does anyone know how to do this.

Here is my `log4j.properties` :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.logger.io.netty=DEBUG
log4j.logger.io.projectreactor=DEBUG
log4j.logger.reactor.netty.http=DEBUG

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

Here is my `logging.properties` :

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level = ALL

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%1$tF %1$tT] [%4$s] %5$s %n

io.netty.level=ALL
io.projectreactor.level=ALL
reactor.netty.http=ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.    I'm using Lombok SLF4j and I needed this `log4j2.xml` config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="OFF">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_LOC">logs</Property>
        <Property name="MAX">5</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p] %c: %m%n
        </Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="FILE" fileName="${LOG_LOC}/main.log"
                     filePattern="${LOG_LOC}/main.%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>

            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>

            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${MAX}" />
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="io.netty" level="debug" />
        <Logger name="io.projectreactor" level="debug" />
        <Logger name="reactor.netty.http" level="debug" />
        <Logger name="com.azure.cosmos" level="debug" />

        <Logger name="file" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Also works with a `log4j.properties` if you add these dependencies in addition to Lombok:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.36</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.36</version>
</dependency>
```